# Find PDF of $Y=-2\ln X$ given that $X$ is uniform on $(0,1)$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X$ have a uniform distribution with p.d.f. $f(x) = 1$, $x$ is in $(0, 1)$, zero elsewhere.
Find the p.d.f. of $Y = -2 \ln X$.

I don't think this is a very difficult question, I just don't really understand what it is asking or where to start. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Update: I did
$$F(y)= P(Y \le y) = P(-2\ln x \le y) = P(\ln x \ge -y/2) = P(x \ge e^{-y/2}).$$
Then $ x=e^{-y/2}$ and $dx/dy =-1/2e^{-y/2}$
Is this all I need to do? Also, I'm not 100% sure why I am using inequalities here- can someone give me a quick explanation?

Comment: You could start with finding the CDF of $Y$. Its derivative is the PDF of $Y$. If you get stuck on that then edit your question to add your efforts.

Comment: Note that $P(x\ge\lambda)=1-\lambda$

Comment: Please I need help wit this. It is known that a particular coin is twice as likely to turn up tails as heads. If the coin is tossed independently, what Is the probability that the 3rd head occurs on the 5th toss?

Answer (score 2):

you are asked to find the probability distribution of the random variable $Y$ that is related to the random variable $X$ by the relation $Y=-2\ln X$, being $X$ uniform in the interval $[0,1]$. You can solve it considering a change of variable applied to the cumulative function $F(x)$:
$$F(x)=\int_0^x f(x)dx = \int_\infty^y f(y)\Big|\frac{dx}{dy}\Big|^{-1}dy$$
so that
$$f(y) = f(x)\Big|\frac{dx}{dy}\Big|_y$$
and in your situation $x=\exp(-y/2)$, so $\Big|\frac{dx}{dy}\Big|_y = \frac{1}{2}\exp(-y/2)$, so $$f(y)= \frac{1}{2}\exp(-y/2)$$

If you try to integrate $f(y)$ between $\infty$ and $0$ you can verify that it gives you $1$.

Comment: Negative density? On y<0?

Comment: sorry, I forgot the absolute value around the derivative

Comment: at this page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution you can find exactly application to probability of change of variables in integration

Comment: Thank you! Is my thought process in the edit correct? And where would the absolute value come in if my solution is valid?

Comment: Sorry, why are you able to use absolute values here? And how did you choose 0 and inf as the range for f(y). Thank you!!

Comment: Integration limits came directly from the input range once you apply on it the coordinate transformation.  You know that y=-2lnx so taking the limit for x going to 0 you have y going to infinity and taking the limit for x going to 1 you have y going to 0.

Answer (score -1):

Let $f(x)=1_{(0,1)}(x)=F_{X}'(x)$. Note that
$$F_{Y}(y)=P(X\geq e^{-y/2})=1-P(X\leq e^{-y/2})=1-F_{X}(e^{-y/2}).$$
Then the density is
\begin{align}
F_{Y}'(y)&=(1-F_{X}(e^{-y/2}))'\\
&=-F_{X}'(e^{-y/2})\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} y}(e^{-y/2})\\
&=-1_{(0,1)}(e^{-y/2})\cdot \left ( -\frac{1}{2}e^{-y/2} \right )\\
&=1_{(0,\infty)}(y)\frac{1}{2}e^{-y/2}.
\end{align}

Comment: $$(\ln(X^{-2})\leq y)=(X\geq e^{-y/2})\ne(X\leq e^{2y})$$

Comment: No. See previous comment.

Comment: Have you tried verifying that your answer is in fact a density? (area under the curve equals $1$)?

Answer (score -1):

$ P(-2logX\le x)=P(logX\ge -x/2)=P(X\ge e^{\frac{-x}{2}})=\int_{e^{\frac{-x}{2}}}^1dt=1-e^{\frac{-x}{2}}$

$F_X(x)=1-e^{\frac{-x}{2}}$

hence $f_X(x)=\frac{1}{2}e^{\frac{-x}{2}}$
which is the pdf of exponential with parameter $\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score -2):

It was such a long time ago I did this, but this seems to work too. At least in my computer simulations. **Maybe it is just a coincidence** it works for this particular function, if that is the case, please show me why.

$Y = -2 \ln(X)$ means that if a sample of X is x, then the corresponding sample of Y is $y = -2\ln(x)$

$y = \ln(x^{-2})$ and then $e^y = x^{-2}$ and $e^{-y/2} = x$. We see that since x is between 0 and 1, y will be between 0 and infinity. Now we just need to normalize, i.e. find $k$ so that $\int_0^\infty ke^{-y/2} dy = 1$ and that is an easy exercise in calculus.

Comment: Is this saying that if $X=g(Y)$ (probably with $g$ monotonous and) with $X$ is uniform on $(0,1)$ then a multiple of $g$ is the PDF of $Y$? **Not so**. Rather, in this setting, assuming that $g$ is strictly decreasing,$$P(Y\leqslant y)=P(X\geqslant g(y))=1-g(y)$$ hence $$f_Y(y)=-g'(y)$$

Comment: Always slightly surprising to see that, roughly two years later, no correction occurred...

Comment: No @Did it was 3 years ago, since 2018-2015 = 3 . I was busy doing other things. I still don't understand your question in comment. Even if I was sure it was wrong I would rather edit with a remark than delete.

Comment: 0. My comment was posted roughly 2 years ago, not 3 years ago (the point of your (wrong) remark being?). 1. What prevented you from asking for explanations, if you needed some, if really you found something unclear in my comment, instead of letting the thing sleep? 2. What exactly is unclear in my comment? Please be specific.

Comment: I don't understand anything about how you interpreted my answer.

Comment: If you are at your most constructive with this pair of comments, indeed nothing to be done here (but you could skip the "interpret" part, there is nothing to interpret here, only a blatantly false post).

Comment: Ah now I remember, interpolating from your last post. I realized it would not be worth my time to try to respond.

Comment: Trying to be insulting, I can see. Not worth more time.

Comment: I meant more like I can't understand your comment and I thought it was unlikely that an explanation would make me more able to understand it. So asking for a clarification would likely waste both of our times.